# android Editext setText should not focused and blinking cursor

Tags: android, textbox

in my activity

1 editext field and 2 check boxes

i do setText("default text") in oncreate.

when my application lods display default text also blinking cursor inside the text field also shows orange border tells it is having focus.

i don't want to be text field focus on create instead it should focus on some where else i did request focus on rest of the checkboxes but it didn't work out textfield still having focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this problem myself

```
View okBtn =findViewById(R.id.tlSettingOK);
            okBtn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            okBtn.requestFocusFromTouch();
```